# SSIS File System Task can copy but can't move file

Tags: ssis

I need to move a file into a folder. However, the package can be successfully executed only when I set the Operation to be "Copy". If it's set to be "Move", it will fail with an error "Could not find a part of the path".
It looks like a access problem, but I'm able to manually cut/delete the source file (right click, then cut/delete). Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a known bug, I have got around it in the past by using rename.  You can also use copy then delete.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It solves my problem! What a silly and obvious bug for Microsoft.......